# ROS Remote Network Setting with Port Forwarding Problem

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As title, I was using ROS for about 5 months, currently I have to move the simulation part to another Virtual Machine which was built on a cloud server and the port is forwarding from local_IP:11311 to global_IP:50230,  here I face the problem for the network setting.

Computers' setting are as below:Q

- Computer 1 as a data saving computer :
- Local wifi network ip =  192.168.0.80
- Port 22 Forwarding to = Lab_IP:29
- ROS_MASTER_URI = http://Cloud_IP:50230
- ROS_HOSTNAME = 192.168.0.80 / Lab_IP ( I've tried both configuration but in vain )
- ROS_IP = 192.168.0.80 / Lab_IP
- Computer 2 as ROS MASTER:
- Local network ip =  192.168.101.83
- Port 11311 Forwarding to =  Cloud_IP:50230
- ROS_MASTER_URI = http://192.168.101.83:11311
- ROS_HOSTNAME = 192.168.101.83
- ROS_IP = 192.168.101.83

The problem I'm facing now is that I can do rostopic list but when I echo those rostopic, it shows

> WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
> Is /clock being published?

Is there anything that I misunderstood at the tutorial ?

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275963/ros-remote-network-setting-with-port-forwarding-problem/) by [showay](https://answers.ros.org/users/32635/showay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally get this problem done.

So here's how i solve the problem:

1. I use my router as a openvpn server
2. As a client, he remote computer owns a local ip of my local environment.
3. All ip and master_uri settings are just like what to do with local computers.

That's it !

---

Originally posted by [showay](https://answers.ros.org/users/32635/showay/) with karma: 16 on 2017-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem might be with firewall. ROS uses other ports apart from the ones configured for ROS_MASTER_URI. It is recommended to start a vpn that would allow access to all ports.
You can confirm this using `netstat` on both sides. when you try to echo, the request will end up in `SYN_SENT`.

---

Originally posted by [ninja777](https://answers.ros.org/users/32648/ninja777/) with karma: 101 on 2017-11-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [showay](https://answers.ros.org/users/32635/showay/) on 2017-11-16**:
Thank you soooo much for your help!
I've been setting up a open VPN server through my router and connect the cloud server to my router, finally I can echo the topic.
However, when I opened gazebo client, it still not able to connect to the master.
Still figuring out what to do.